# Unique list of structure

Tags: c++, list, struct, unique

I have a list of the following structure

```
struct Element
{
   int id;
   int groupID;

  };
```

I want to know how many unique groups there are

for example

```
 list<Element> myElements;
  Element e;
  e.id = 0;
  e.groupID = 2;
  myElements.push_back(e);

  e.id = 1;
  e.groupID = 0;
  myElements.push_back(e);

  e.id = 2;
  e.groupID = 2;
  myElements.push_back(e);

  e.id = 3;
  e.groupID = 1;
  myElements.push_back(e);
```

There are 4 elements here but only 3 unique group ids 0, 1, 2

I'm trying to look for an efficient way to do that because my list grows in size.

I tried this

```
struct groupID_unique {
  bool operator() (Element first, Element second)
    { return (first.groupID != second.groupID); }
     };

    myElements.unique(groupID_unique());
```

But this returns to me the 2 un-repetitive ids 0,1

Comment: `unique` is the wrong way to go for a couple more reasons. It's only really useful on a sorted list (only consecutive duplicates are considered duplicates) and it's destructive (it removes the duplicates it finds)

Answer (score 2):

Use a set to store the items (temporarily). A set will store only the unique items. The size of the set is the number of unique items.

Add an equality comparator for the object:

```
struct Element {
  bool operator==(Element const& rhs) const {
    return id == rhs.id && groupId == rhs.groupId;
  }
};
```

Use a `set`.

```
std::set<Element> elementSet{elementList.begin(), elementList.end()};
size_t const numUniqueElements = elementSet.size();
```

Note that there is some cost (time and space complexity) in constructing the `set`. If you want to keep the repetitions for some other purpose, then you can continue with the `list` otherwise you can switch from the `list` and `set` so that you always have the unique count readily available (through `.size()`)